# What to use to funnel floor air vent in cabinent for proper air flow

Tags: heating, air-conditioning, ventilation, venting

I ripped the "floor" of the kitchen cabinet out to reveal that all along, my vent was funneling air like this, an open hole.  The circular opening is about 6 inches across both ways. I need to funnel it into the air vent but don't know where to start. Any advice would be appreciated. I'm thinking something like this but it just seems like there has to be better angled things I could use?

[image]

Comment: I don't know HVAC or anything, but I wouldn't actually think this was a problem... with the cabinet floor in tact, the vent is getting air flow in there the same way as if the cabinet wasn't there at all: from the area surrounding the hole. What are you concerned about with this?

Comment: I'm concerned about losing small amounts of air through cracks, though it's probably not much of a concern as the employee at Home Depot told me, though I am fixing it anyways due to being ocd sometimes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An air conditioning supply warehouse could fabricate a metal duct for you. Cut a cardboard template before you go. They will like you for that.

Alternatively, you could just fashion something yourself out of air duct foam board and foil tape, both of which should be available at your local hardware store.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing, it is almost finished. I'll post pictures when i'm done... Though great to know about going to a supply warehouse